# Are questions about solidity/EVM used in other blockchains off topic?

Tags: discussion

Recently there were questions about Tron, and regularly we have questions about Quorum. And there are other blockchains using EVM like Qtum or RSK.

For questions that are generic enough it should be OK.

But for others that are too specific about the other blockchains it is more likely that they will not have to be accepted.